# laravel 5.4 homestead setup

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, homestead

when I want add ssh-keygen in cmd  to setup laravel Homestead I recieve this picture:
[image]

and when I want add vagrant up this error occurred:

C:/Windows/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:118:in `read': No such file or directo                                                                                                                ry @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Hanie/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)

and My Homestead.yaml is:

[image]

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the **4096** number on your ssh-keygen command.
Try this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "hanieasemi@gmail.com"
```

Comment: How about `ssh-keygen -t rsa` ? This should be not showing `Too many arguments` message.

Comment: that's Right! But When I add vagrant up in Homestead Directory My computer Restart what can I do?

Comment: Computer restart? I dont really know why, maybe memory alocation is too high? try use 1024 mermory.